# React Native - flex, ScrollView and dynamic height not filling screen

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, flexbox, scrollview, native

I have a dynamic height inside ScrollView - on user interaction the height can either increase or decrease. ScrollView has `flexGrow:1` and the contents inside are wrapped around a View with `flex: 1`.

However, when decreasing the height while being on the bottom of the panel, I get a white 'overscroll-like space' on the bottom which I can remove only by dragging the panel back up.(p.s I have `bounces={false} overScrollMode='never'`)

How can remove that overscroll space when screen has decreased its height.

P.S. I **do not** want to forceUpdate since there are contents I do not wish to be lost/updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think, you have to adjust `contentInset` prop of `ScrollView` when you expand(increase height) and collpase(decrease height) your contents.

```
...
<ScrollView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    contentInset={{top:0, bottom: this.state.contentInsetBottom }}
 >
...
```

You can have some predefined values something like,

```
const bottom_initial = 0;
const arbitrary_move_value = 100;
```

In you state,

```
this.state={
  contentInsetBottom: bottom_initial
}
```

When you expand or collapse, calculate appropriate move value and change the `contentInset`.

```
this.setState({
  contentInsetBottom: arbitrary_move_value
})
```

This is just the idea. You have to calculate appropriate `contentInset`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ScrollView with a View element and give the View the following style. Your container should have "flex: 1" style aswell:

```
<View style={flex: 1}>  
  <View style={{ flexShrink: 1 }}>
    <ScrollView>
     ...
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
</View>
```

This will shrink-grow your ScrollView according to its contents. It will stop growing once it hits the container's limit, the screen's height.